# Initializing variable from PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

```
$q = $db->query(" SELECT username FROM users WHERE userident = '1' ");
echo $q; //error
print_r $q; //prints the query information (SELECT ... etc)
```

How do I go about getting the specific value of the element I am querying? Say the element under column `username` and where `userident` equals '1' contains the value "Patrick"; how do I initialize this string into a variable?

```
//same query as above
$user = $q;
echo $user; //prints "Patrick"
```

Sorry if this is something so rudimentary and mundane, but I've never done this outside of a `foreach()` loop. I'd normally iterate through rows to print specific details. The below works, but the `foreach()` is unnecessary as far as I understand.

```
foreach($q as $p) {
    $user = $p["username"];
}
echo $print; //this correctly prints "Patrick"
```

Surely there's a method I missed somewhere?

Comment: Surely you should try to RTFM ? http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Comment: I've attempted to read the PDO manual, but the stuff I have tried don't work. `$user = $q->fetchAll();` returns an empty array for example.

Comment: What is the "error" you're getting?

Comment: Surely you should try a Real TFM ? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: @deceze, the error for line 2 of the first snippet of code is cannot convert type array into type string. This is expected, that part was solely for demonstration of what I would like. @Your Common Sense, great resource. Thank you for linking it. However, I've tried what it states (`fetchColumn()`) and upon printing it displays nothing.

Comment: Then your query *returned* nothing. You know, the code you get is not a magic chant which intended to get your data in a puff of smoke. It is surely a working code but it cannot fix all other errors you made.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the **Connection** part?

Comment: I'm not an idiot. Of course I did. Everything has been working fine up until now. I'm looking at my table right now and a row exists where `userident = '1'`, but upon querying `SELECT username FROM users WHERE userident = '1'`, it returns an empty result.

Comment: One don't have to be an idiot to do simple mistakes. We all do. Then your code does not that it should you have to *debug* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query method pretty much defeats the purpose of using prepared statements. Plus, I believe for what you're looking for, it isn't quite right.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['id'])) {
        exit;
    }
    $userId = $_POST['id'];

    $db = new PDO(/* Stuff */);

    $sql = '
        SELECT username
        FROM users
        WHERE id = :id';

    // Get a prepared statement object.
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    // Bind a parameter to the SQL code.
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // Actually get the result.
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Close the connection.
    $statement->closeCursor();

    // Print the result.
    print_r($result);
```

Alternately you can use `$statement->fetchAll()` to gather more than one result.

Edit: I didn't actually run this code, so you might have to tinker with it to get it working right.

Comment: Don't you find this code a bit err... boring? A *screenful* of code and miss the goal completely.

Comment: *Whistles. I really missed the ball on that one. That's what I get for scanning the question I guess. If I wake up tomorrow to find I have negative -100 rep, I'll edit the post or something. LOL

Comment: oh, you'd never get even -2. SO is so tolerant. In general.